# Content Security Policy

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, content-security-policy, scriptmanager

I am currently implementing CSP(Content Security Policy) for my project and i have chosen to implement **nonce** for all the inline scripts that cannot be moved away from the web page. While trying to implement nonce for classic aspx pages, there are few places where the script manager is being included to use the ajaxcontrol toolkit and they are generating a  tag in the html.

Since i have **nonce** implementation i need to add the nonce attribute to the script tag in order to prevent the  from getting blocked by the CSP. I have been looking into this for 2 days and i don't find any suggestion/solution for this.

EDIT:

I am generating the nonce using OWIN middleware. The **meta** tag is being generated dynamically and appended to the **meta** tag during the master page load.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Which web server are you using?

Comment: I am using IIS..

Answer (score 0):

On IIS 7 and above, you can leverage the URL Rewrite Module to define outbound rules which allow you to modify the markup on the fly:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-outbound-rules-to-add-web-analytics-tracking-code

Here is an example of rewriting image tags:

http://marisks.net/2017/05/14/changing-static-resource-urls-to-cdn-urls-with-url-rewrite/

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But in my case i just need to include the "nonce" attribute to the script tag to whitelist it because i am using the content-security policy with nonce to whitelist the inline scripts. The script tags generated by the controls using the scriptmanager does not get this attribute as they are rendered to the page dynamically. Will this url rewrite work even for manipulating the script tags generated dynamically? And also i am generating the nonce dynamically that will be changing  for each request. Also is there a way to do this programatically? please share your thoughts.

Answer (score -1):

After a discussion with the microsoft community it has been identified that there is no way to interpret the script tag generated dynamically. So as of now this is kind of not possible. will keep you guys updated if i find any solution or if you guys have a suggestion or workaround then feel free to post it here. Thanks for all your help